# Prevent Object recursion/loop by reference in PHP

Tags: php, loops, object, recursion, reference

Haven't found an answer yet but I'm sure there must be one: how do I prevent an object recursion/loop when objects reference each other? An example:

```
class Patient {
    private $Issues = array();

    [...]

    public function __construct($id) {
        [ Get data from DB ]
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->Issues[$row['idIssue']] = new Issue($row['idIssue']);
        }
        [...]
    } 
}

class Issue {
    private $Patient;

    [...]

    public function __construct($id) {
        [ Get data from DB ]
        $this->Patient = new Patient($row['idPatient']); <-- Leads to recursion as the patient will load all it's Issues() etc. etc.
        [...]
    }
}
```

How do I prevent this? I could use the id of the Patient() instead of the real object but that feels like a hack. Is there a way to use the real object?

Comment: Have the `Issue` constructor take a `Patient` instance instead? However, having cyclic dependencies is generally considered an anti-pattern. Does the issue absolutely need to know about the patient?

Comment: Thank you, that's what been suggested below. Issues don't necessarily need to know about patients but I have other classes which need to know about each other.

Answer (score 1):

Do not recreate object. Just pass the instance of the *master* object to the *detail* constructor. E.g.:

```
class Patient {
    private $Issues = array();

    [...]

    public function __construct($id) {
        [ Get data from DB ]
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->Issues[$row['idIssue']] = new Issue($row['idIssue'], $this);
        }
        [...]
    } 
}

class Issue {
    private $Patient;

    [...]

    public function __construct($id, Patient $patient) {
        [ Get data from DB ]
        $this->Patient = $patient
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! One question though: shouldn't the "Patient" object be passed by reference (to save memory/execution time)? Like so:
```public function __construct($id, Patient &$patient) {
        [ Get data from DB ]
        $this->Patient = &$patient
        [...]
    }```

Comment: This is the case in his example. Objects are passed as references already. Check this [fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c38d024286a6e03e7835000f24fd99e4f25a6292)

Answer (score 1):

You can (should !) separate the DB connection/queries from the entities definitions and pass references to relations, otherwise, you can't mock entities, plus mixing DB connection and entities definition goes against the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) :

```
// somewhere in your code
$idPatient = 42;
$patient = new Patient();
$patient->setId($idPatient);

// get datas from DB
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $issue = new Issue();
    $issue->setId($row['idIssue'])
          ->setPatient($patient);

    $patient->addIssue($issue);

    // or, shorter way :
    // $patient->addIssues((new Issue())->setId($row['idIssue'])
    //                                  ->setPatient($patient));
}

class Patient {
    private $Issues = array();
    private $Id;

    public function addIssue(Issue $issue): self
    {
        $this->Issues[] = $issue;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->Id = $id;

        return $this;
    }
}

class Issue {
    private $Patient;
    private $Id;

    public function addPatient(Patient $patient): self
    {
        $this->Patient = $patient;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->Id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I get your points and the elegance of it. However, for me keeping the PHP objects and the DB models in sync makes the code more readable too me.

Comment: This is a bad practice. You can't create fake objects and can't create new objects that aren't yet in DB if you query the DB in the constructor

Comment: If you are working some days with an ORM such as Doctrine, your entities will be like this and DB stuff will be separated from entities definitions